# No blocking operation in MongoJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I have to do an operation that calculate for me something, but I can't use the result of it, because I always stay in a wait state, in fact in my terminal remains in execution my program until I enter ctrl+C.

I have a main in nodejs for my program where I need to use my result calculated in a module.

```
var myJSONClient = {
    "nombre" : "<nombre_cliente>",
    "intervalo" : [0,0]
    };


var intervalo = gestionar.gestion(myJSONClient,vector_intervalo); 
console.log("intervalo: "+intervalo); //return undefined
```

And this is the module

```
var gestion = function(myJSON,vector_intervalo) { 
var dburl = 'localhost/mongoapp';
var collection = ['clientes'];
var db = require('mongojs').connect(dburl, collection );
var intervalo_final;

    function cliente(nombre, intervalo){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.intervalo = intervalo; 
    }

    var cliente1 = new cliente(myJSON.nombre,myJSON.intervalo);

    db.clientes.save(cliente1, function(err, saveCliente){
    if (err || !saveCliente) console.log("Client "+cliente1.nombre+" not saved Error: "+err);
    else console.log("Client "+saveCliente.nombre+" saved");
        intervalo_final = calculate(vector_intervalo);

        console.log(intervalo_final); //here I can see the right content of the variable intervalo_final

    });

console.log(intervalo_final); //this is not executed
return intervalo_final;
}

exports.gestion = gestion;
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the async world! :)

First of all, *you aren't* doing blocking operations in Node. Actually, networking in Node is fully asynchronous.

The part you state the `console.log` works it's because the callback function of the `db.clientes.save` call. That callback states your mongo save has finished.

**What asynchronous networking means?**
It means that your save will be processed sometime in the future. The script will not wait for the response to continue the code. The `console.log` right after the save call will be executed soon as it's reached.

As for the "wait state" of your script, that it never ends, you should take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698834/how-does-a-node-js-process-know-when-to-stop). There's the answer.