# How does `server.listen()` keep the node program running

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

`Node.js` program is terminated when the event loop is empty. If I use `http` module and create a server without any callback to be added to event loop, the program is terminated:

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer();
```

However, if I add `listen`, the program keeps running:

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer();
server.listen(5155);
```

So how does `listen` method keep the process running even if I don't add anything to event loop? Does it adds something to event loop? How does it interact with it?

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L1337 ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698834/how-does-a-node-js-process-know-when-to-stop/7699579#7699579

Comment: @zerkms, Paulpro thanks, I'll explore

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two things here:

If you look at the Node.js documentation about server.listen(...) it says on the first line:

> **Begin** accepting connections on the specified port and hostname...

and:

> This function is asynchronous. When the server has been bound,
>   'listening' event will be emitted...

This per se is not enough to answer your question. So let's take a look at the code.

The `listen()` method (https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L1292)
ends up calling `self._listen2()` method. There in the last line:

```
process.nextTick(emitListeningNT, this);
```

(https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L1276)

wich is a callback to:

```
function emitListeningNT(self) {
  // ensure handle hasn't closed
  if (self._handle)
    self.emit('listening');
}
```

(https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L1285).

This way, unless node.js detects an error or some other stop condition it will keep running.