# How does Node keep a server process alive?

Tags: node.js, server, process

When Node's event loop is fully drained, the process exists. However this doesn't happen on an HTTP server for example, because of `server.listen()`. But what does that function do exactly?

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js) and [an old incomplete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137902/how-does-server-listen-keep-the-node-program-running), it eventually calls `self._listen2()` which emits a "listening" event on `process.nextTick`, and gets an async hook ID from`DefaultTriggerAsyncId()`.

However, I still don't get it. What am I missing here? How does only this code cause the event loop to keep 'idling'? How is the function wrapped on the C side? Where's the line of code that actually does that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The real answer [finally came from Bert Belder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNa9OMajw9w), who worked on libuv.

Every time Node queues an action that will resolve at some point in the future, think async functions or timers, it has a ref – a mark to remind itself it’s waiting on some future work. The event loop checks if there are any refs. If the ref counter is 0 , Node exits the process. If there are refs, the event loop goes back to the start and does its thing. You can think of it as a super simple `while(refCounter)` loop.

So, what happens with a server? This exact process, except the listen function doesn’t decrement the ref counter. The event loop sees there’s always at least one ref left, so it never ends the process instead goes back to the start and loops until something new happens.

You can see this by using `server.unref()` on the server object with the net or http modules. The unref method, available on other objects as well, tells Node to ignore the ref for that specific function when counting at the end of the event loop. If you run the code below you’ll see Node closes the process, even though it starts listening to the port.

```
const http = require("http");

    http
      .createServer((req, res) => {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end("Bye bye");
      })
      .listen(3333)
      .unref();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain a few steps here: 
1. You start your server on a particular port, what it does is "It start a process which is a server process, this process runs something like

```
while(true){
   readdatafromport();
   if(unhandledexceptionHappened){
      killtheServerProcess();
     }
 }
```

It keeps reading unless an exception happened. If an exception happened, it kills the server process and your HTTP server goes down or becomes dead.

2. When the code below executes:

   ```
    server.listen()
   ```

   It is just registering to listen on the port if any new data come here. In TCP/IP, when a client makes a call to the server, they basically writing their quest on the server PORT(I say it for easy explanation). Since server processing is listening for the change in the port, it can respond to that. If you understand how node event works, hopefully, you understand how server process can manage many many requests concurrently.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it's besides the question. I was asking how come Node doesn't exit a process with server.listen, and how that function interacts with the event loop.